# Google Maps API markers and polylines disappeared in Qt4 after latest API version release

Tags: javascript, qt, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, qt4

My Qt4 application had markers and polylines in Google Maps which were working fine until few days back. I didn't make any code changes but suddenly the markers and polylines disappeared. I tried loading diffrent API versions, still no luck.

The same code I use give markers in online code editors. Is there change in Maps API that Qt4 cannot handle ?

Am I missing something in marker options ? Please reply

The below 3 files are working sample of the application

javascript file: Maps.js

```
function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        }

        var Map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0)
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                position: latLng,
                                                map: Map                                       
                                           })
       }

      function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&callback=initialize";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    window.onload = loadScript;
```

HTML file: index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100%; width: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100%; width: 100% }    
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Maps.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

QML File: main.qml

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import QtWebKit 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: mainRect
    width: 800
    height: 600

    WebView {
        id: webViewer
        anchors.fill: parent
        preferredHeight: height
        preferredWidth: width
        url: "qrc:///Maps/index.html"
        settings.developerExtrasEnabled : true
        pressGrabTime: 0
    }
}
```

I tried calling setMarker(), the markers won't come.
Also tried specifying api version, no luck

Comment: No errors in the F12 developer tools?

Comment: How do you call the API? Show the bootstrap please and provide some context for your issue.

Comment: @JeroenHeier The map is not loaded in a normal browser. I cannot get Developer tools. Map is loaded using QtWebKit in a QML WebView. If you know how to enable developer tools in Webview, please guide me. I set developerExtrasEnabled to true, not sure I am using it correctly

Comment: @rags2riches I use QtWebKit to view webcontent. Its component WebView loads my html file and a javascript file for the map.

Comment: I have edited my question and added more code for any clarification.

Comment: Probably the webview you use doesn't fully supports ES6 standards. Note that the [latest version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases) of Maps JavaScript API relies on ES6. That why Google deprecated support for outdated browsers: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport